# How to retrieve output value from stored procedure if exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In SqlServer Management Studio when I execute stored procedure and it throws exception it also returns output values.

I can't figure how to get that values from C# .NET - when exception is thrown execution is stopped and output values isn't populated.

Comment: Hmm, [According to this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/06/09/624531.aspx) the output parameters shouldn't get populated on error but I just tested and they seem to (for this case `CREATE PROC FOO @I INT OUTPUT AS SET @I=10 SELECT 1/0`)

Comment: Why would you need an output value from a stored procedure that failed? It sounds like a bad practice. I'd suggest catching an exception and using default values in that case, that you provide from your C# code, if you really need them, or even better - leave the exception bubble up and handle it in the application accordingly.

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov, With output parameters i can get additional information if exception is thrown

Comment: Further to my comment above it appears as though they are populated unless a [batch aborting error](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#statementbatch) is encountered. `SELECT CAST('FISH' AS INT)` leaves them unpopulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can use [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx) - this return specified information to the application. This might not be an ideal practice, mind you; and also might be too late for you if you don't have control of the stored procedure to implement this.

Comment: You can get additional information in the Errors collection of the SqlException being thrown. Furthermore, you can use RAISERROR as suggested in the answer above and the Errors collection will contain the information for each error thrown by RAISERROR

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of both the stored procedure and the code that is executing the stored procedure, then another alternative that we use extensively is to use an OUTPUT stored procedure parameter to return error codes to the caller (i.e. @ErrorCode INT = 0 OUTPUT).

In my opinion, this has a few benefits over raising errors:

1) Exception handling is a very expensive operation in the .net framework. If all you need is to do is tell the user that there is something wrong with the data they entered or there is a conflict in the database, returning an error code will have a much smaller impact on the performance of the application and server than throwing and catching exceptions.

2) If your procedure has made it far enough in its processing, you can populate other parameters. For example, if you need to include information on which user has a record locked, you can include this information in another output parameter and build your error message in code.

3) It can be easier to support message internationalization or customization through this method than through error messages encoded in stored procedures.

Comment: I’m already doing this. I set `@bitErrorCondition1` or `@bitErrorCondition2` depending on what is wrong so that my calling code can figure out what went wrong instead of parsing the text of my `RAISERROR` call. It works fine from .net, but when I try to read output variables set by a sproc from a T-SQL batch, none of the `OUTPUT` parameters are ever set.

Comment: I.e., I want to still use `RAISERROR` so that I can’t accidentally continue as if nothing went wrong. I want to see an error instead of having a silent failure accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLServer methods to retrieve exception data if you are encapsulating your query in a try catch block as this:

```
BEGIN TRY
 --SQL Statements
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  --exception details

    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER()  
    SELECT ERROR_STATE()  
    SELECT ERROR_SEVERITY()  
    SELECT ERROR_LINE()  
    SELECT ERROR_PROCEDURE()  
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()   

END CATCH
```

If you are not running a try catch block. SqlServer stores errors in its logs and you can read it with t-sql using:

```
EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 1
```